# django rest сигнатурная подпись запросов

Tags: android, django, api, signature

нигде не могу найти информацию как осуществить сигнатурную подпись обращения к api. В django есть встроенный класс django.core.signing, но как его использовать например в android приложении, как сформировать подпись к запросу, что бы на сервере ее можно было декодировать и провалидировать запрос ? Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использовать Django REST + JWT http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/ и на стороне Android соответственно посылать и продлевать токен через Retrofit / OkHTTP3 Interceptor.

Comment: в django есть собственный механизм авторизации на основе токенов, просто дело в секьюрности. Как быть если злоумышленник завладел токеном? Надо проверить сигнатуру, а вот как ее создать пока не нашел ответа.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю механизм - на стороне сервера мы подписываем часть формы и зашиваем ключи и потом на стороне же сервера проверяем его (не поменяли ли часть формы), верно? Для Android это не имеет смысла так как ключ так или иначе выкусят, поэтому нужны более сложны механизмы подписи.